# How to return True if there are 1+ RegEx Matches for a range of data

Tags: google-sheets

I assume RegExMatch is the base of the solution but let me know if I am mistaken.

I want the function to return True if there is a single quotation mark in the entire column and return False otherwise.

Here is some example data and my lame attempt.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GVgZtoWdY6jfDqv5uc1Pq_Be6NrObwStC6Z92RrWMAM/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to use the function COUNTIF when it comes to a single quotation mark so you can easily count with conditionals.

```
 =COUNTIF(A1:A6,"*""")=1
```

### Reference

[COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480): Returns a conditional count across a range.

Comment: forgot about countif, thanks so much, what does "*""" represent?

Comment: The asterisks is the wildcard to match zero or more characters up to the quote. It's a tripple quote just to make GS be aware we looking for one.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
=REGEXMATCH(QUERY(A:A,,9^9), CHAR(34))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

=REGEXMATCH(A1:A,"""+")

Comment: thanks, how does this work, what does the """+" represent?